# R Print x value when y value first equals zero

Tags: r

I am using data on populations over time and want to identify the first year at which the population reaches zero. My data looks similar to this:

```
population<- c(500,50,25,2,0,0,0,0)
year<-(1:8)
dat<-data.frame(year,population)
```

I want to produce a value showing the year at which the population first reaches zero, so in this case that would be 5. I have tried using if and ifelse functions so that when the population is above zero it is NA and when it equals zero it is equivalent to 'year' but this just starts to print the year numbers in order rather than selecting the year that corresponds to the first 0 population row. It also gets a little confused as there are multiple zero population years but I am only interested in the first one.

Any suggestions/ideas on how to do this better and make it work would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset a dataframe based on a condition: in your case, observations where population = 0.

```
dat[dat$population == 0, ]

  year population
5    5          0
6    6          0
7    7          0
8    8          0
```

Wrap that in the minimum function and select the year column and you have your solution:

```
min(dat[dat$population == 0,]$year) 
[1] 5
```

Comment: There is no need for using `which`. `dat[dat$population == 0, ]` will give the same as `dat[which(dat$population == 0), ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` to find where `population` hits first time `0`. In case it is sorted it finds the first year.

```
dat$year[match(0, dat$population)]
#[1] 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Subset all == 0 then take the first

```
head(dat$year[dat$population == 0],n=1)
[1] 5
```

or

```
dat$year[dat$population == 0][1]
[1] 5
```